# Joomla get article nice URL

Tags: php, joomla

I am new to Joomla and am trying to develop a module under 3.1. I managed to get the selected article ID and title in the module options but I don't know how to get the url to the ID, something similar to get_permalink(ID) in Wordpress.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You would want to run the url through JRoute to get the full url. You would also need to know how Joomla articles are usually built.

```
$url = JRoute::_('index.php?option=com_content&view=article&id='.$id);
```

This assumes that you have the id in the variable `$id`. For the rest of the url you would need to know the component you are calling (added as the option like above, Content manager is always `com_content`) and the view (which for an article is `article`). You can see the different views available for com_content by checking the file structure under `/components/com_content/views/`. Besides `Article`, you should see `articles`, `categories`, and `category` as well as a few other.